# How do I search multiple mySQL tables to find one specific row?

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables: adapters, connectors, components
I need to be able to search them all to find a corresponding Part Number (part_num)
The part number is unique so I don't have to worry about multiple entries.

I use GET to find the part number in the URL, set it to $num, and then do the SELECT

What I've found is that I should use UNION, however the three tables have different columns and it gives me an error when trying to do the select.  In the example below

[Using UNION to find references from other tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558283/how-do-i-find-all-references-from-other-tables-to-a-specific-row)

This is my code:

```
if(isset($_GET['num'])) {
$num = $_GET['num'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM connectors WHERE part_num = '$num' UNION SELECT * FROM adapters WHERE part_num = '$num' UNION SELECT * FROM components WHERE part_num = '$num'"); }
```

Any help would be appreciated, so thanks in advance SO =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably have a fourth table `Parts` that identifies to which type table each `part_num` has been allocated.  However, without that, you could still get what you're after with outer joins (wasteful though):

```
SELECT * FROM
             connectors
   LEFT JOIN adapters   USING(part_num)
   LEFT JOIN components USING(part_num)
WHERE
   part_num = ?
```

Note that I have used `?` as you **really** should be using prepared statements: if you don't know why, or what they are, read about [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you.  I have one other question that I forgot to include though.  How might I know which of these tables was selected with the correct part number using this method?

Comment: @Jweb: With the above method, you would have to test the resulting records to see which columns are `NULL`.  Another approach would be similar to [my answer to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10324939/623041), in which you make `UNION` work by inserting literal columns as required to align the results: one such literal could flag from which table the results originate.  Note that approach ought to be more efficient than the above as you avoid making unnecessary cross-joins.

Comment: Thanks for responding eggyal =) I will up vote up your post when I get 15 reputation!

Answer (score 1):

How about taking not all columns, but only titles or so on?

```
$sSql = "SELECT id, title, 1 FROM connectors WHERE part_num = '$num' 
UNION 
SELECT id, title, 2 FROM adapters WHERE part_num = '$num' 
UNION 
SELECT id, title, 3 FROM components WHERE part_num = '$num'";
```

You must adopt it to your table fields, but with this logic you will have an array where by the Third column (in my example), you can know if it is connector, adapter or component found, then generate proper links or do other actions with this data.

Another Way is to make Multi query, which will return multiple results by one database request. There are some ways to use it - using mysqli (http://lt.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) or some of Adodb or PDO libraries.

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

To use UNION, the 3 recordsets *must* have the same number of columns, so you'll have to specifed which columns from each table that you want.  From there, you'll have a single results set with the data from each of the 3 queries.